# Android studio: Merging errors

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Estoy tratando de hacer build de un proyecto desde android studio, pero veo este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al abrir la pestaña de Merged manifest veo este mensaje,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al parecer esta es la linea del error, ¿alguien sabe como podría arreglarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de definir un `FileProvider` personalizado, pero la clase no existe, la clase FileProvider debe existir dentro del paquete `com.ReactNativeBlobUtil.Utils`

De otra forma, puedes usar la clase `"androidx.core.content.FileProvider"` que se tiene en el SDK :

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
```